# Calculate user input from form and display results - Django

Tags: python, django

I have a form to calculate the weight of a postal tray - the form works and when i submit it goes to the database. However, what I'd like to do now is take the information submitted in those fields and do some math to give the calculation they need.

views.py

```
@login_required
def tray_calc_view(request):
    model = TrayCalcModel
    tray_form = TrayCalcForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        tray_form = TrayCalcForm(request.POST)
        if tray_form.is_valid():
            tray_form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('tray_weight')
    return render(request, "tray_weight_calculator.html", {'tray_form': tray_form})
```

models.py

```
class TrayCalcModel(models.Model):
    sheets = models.IntegerField(max_length=30)
    paper_weight = models.IntegerField(max_length=30)
```

I'd like to submit the form and it take me to a new page with the filled in form and a box with the calculation in. I'd like to be able to update that form on this page and recalculate and it update that calculation.

urls.py

```
path('tray-weight-calculator/', tray_calc_view, name="tray_weight"),
```

My form is at tray-weight-calculator/ and I'd like the calculated form to be at tray-weight-calculator/calculated-weight

How would I need to set up my views.py to do this?

Answer (score 1):

you have to add after form.is_valid() a cleaned_data.get method you also can add a third field call result in your model class to save the result to the model:

```
def tray_calc_view(request):
    model = TrayCalcModel
    tray_form = TrayCalcForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        tray_form = TrayCalcForm(request.POST)
        if tray_form.is_valid():
            sheets = tray_form.cleaned_date.get('sheets')
            paper_weight = tray_form.cleaned_data.get('paper_weight')
            calculation = int(sheets) * int(paper_weight)
            tray_form.save(commit=True)
            return redirect('tray_weight')
    return render(request, "tray_weight_calculator.html", {'tray_form': tray_form})
```